# Comments History showing twice on Custom Edit Form while doing document check out

Tags: document-library, custom, version-history, version-comments

I have custom edit form for shared document and there i have comment history field. Comments History is showing twice on Custom Edit Form while doing document check out(automatically) because I have enabled the "Require Check Out" property. If I disable the "Require Check Out" property, then its displaying properly. How to resolve this issue?